# GoogleMaps: when I put an anchor, the marker becomes default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I’m trying to make my own marker on the map, but the problem is that it moves out when the map is zoomed, I read here about the fact that I need to add an anchor

[Google Maps v3 custom marker icon does not keep it's position on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321752/google-maps-v3-custom-marker-icon-does-not-keep-its-position-on-map)

I added an anchor, but the marker immediately becomes default, tell me why?

```
  const position = {
  lat: 52.263810,
  lng: 104.311577
}

const goldStar = {
  path: 'M 10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z',
  anchor: {position} // here i added anchor
  // path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
  // path: 'M 10, 20' +
  //   '    a 10,10 0 1,1 20,0' +
  //   '    a 10,10 0 1,1 -20,0',
  // fillColor: 'yellow',
  // fillOpacity: 0.8,
  // scale: 1,
  // strokeColor: 'gold',
  // strokeWeight: 2
};

 <Marker
            position={position}
            onClick={() => console.log(343)}
            icon={goldStar}
          />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`anchor` is type of `Point`,[Icon interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon)

> The position at which to anchor an image in correspondence to the location of the marker on the map. By default, the anchor is located along the centre point of the bottom of the image.

So, the right way is :

```
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,25) //Point(x,y),depend on youe icone size
```

With `@react-google-maps` library

```
 anchor:  { x: 10, y: 15 }
```

Comment: Now the marker goes up (((how to make it always be above the point in the center?

Comment: I added anchor:  { x: 52.263810, y: 104.311577 }

Comment: ok, now I understand, I need to enter the size of the icon thanks thanks thanks